# Getting error in Application class during unit testing

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric

I am getting weird exception when i am trying to execute my application class through robolectric. 
    I am stuck from several hours on it.
    Could someone please help me on it?
My code snippet is given below:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

at android.test.ApplicationTestCase.__constructor__(ApplicationTestCase.java:5)
at android.test.ApplicationTestCase.<init>(ApplicationTestCase.java)
at com.grapplemobile.tmcplus.TmcPlusApplicationTest.<init>(TmcPlusApplicationTest.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.createTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:520)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:266)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:263)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner.methodBlock(RobolectricTestRunner.java:530)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:247)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

My Code is following:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk = 18)
public class MyApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<MyApplication>{
  private MyApplication application;

   public  MyApplicationTest ()
  {
      super(MyApplication.class);
   }
   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
      // super.setUp();
      createApplication();
      application = getApplication();

   }

   @Test
   public void testonCreate() throws Exception {
   application.onCreate();
  }
```

Comment: Please remove `extends ApplicationTestCase`. You're already running it from JVM and not on device. Correct?

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Yes i am running it from JVM . I need application instance for my test cases which is coming null . So i searched that createApplication() will create application instance. If i i will remove ApplicationTestCase then how i would be able to get application instance?

Comment: Yes you are write Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix JUnit tests with instrumental tests:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class,sdk = 18)
public class MyApplicationTest{
}
```

If you need the instance of the application then use `RuntimeEnvironment.application`. If you want to test Application itself then just create it with `new` and call methods on it, but it should be not `Robolectric` test

Comment: RuntimeEnvironment.application deprecated